# How can I call a method that is inside a UIViewController embedded in a container from a parent UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, protocols

I have an ios app in swift and I have a `UIViewController` (let's call it parentController) with a container. This container embeds another `UIViewController` called embedController.

embedController contains a method that prints a message to a console.

How can I call this method from my parentController?

I tried to use protocols, my current code is as follows:

```
class ParentController: UIViewController {

    var handleEmbedController:HandleEmbedController?


        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "embedViewSegue"){

        if let embed = segue.destinationViewController as? EmbedController {
            embed.value1 = value1
        }

    }

    @IBAction func sendMsgButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        handleEmbedController?.printMsg() //this so far does nothing


    }



}
```

and my embedController:

```
protocol HandleEmbedController: class {
    func printMsg()
}

class EmbedController: UITableViewController, HandleEmbedController{

    var value1 = ""

    func printMsg(){
         print("printing some embedded message")
    }

}
```

How can I print this message from a parent controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing in your prepare for segue? Aren't you supposed to set your delegate (protocol) there? Like this:

```
if (segue.identifier == "embedViewSegue"){

    if let embed = segue.destinationViewController as? EmbedController     {
        self.handleEmbedController = embed
    }

}
```

If you put a breakpoint in `sendMsgButtonAction` you should see that the property `handleEmbedController` is nil. And that's why the method call does nothing since you are safely unwrapping it with `?`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the one part I was missing!!